# Как клонировать элемент HTML созданный в JS с помощью цикла

Tags: javascript, циклы, клонирование

Почему-то div не клонируется до значения i, может я выбрал неправильный метод?

```
document.querySelector(".b12").addEventListener("click", function t12() {
  const elem = document.createElement('div');
  let elemCopy = elem.cloneNode(true);
  let i = 5;
  let outStr = '';
  while (elemCopy.length <= i){
    outStr += elemCopy[i];
    elemCopy++;
  }
  console.log(elemCopy);
  document.querySelectorAll('.out12').innerHTML = outStr;
});



<button class="b12">Push</button>
<div class="div12"></div>
```

Comment: Что такое `elemCopy++;` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Таким образом попытался нарастить цикл.

Comment: Почему он должен наращиваться таким образом? и что значит "нарастить цикл"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Извиняюсь, нет итераций. Насколько я понимаю, если условие цикла не дает undefined/NaN/null, то он должен работать.

Comment: Цикл будет работать до тех пор, пока условие `(elemCopy.length <= i)` истина, т.е. равно `true`

Comment: Цикл должен работать, если условие истино

Comment: @SwaD Вроде бы условие в моем цикле истинно, тогда почему не работает?

Comment: console.log(elemCopy.length) сделайте и посмотрите

Comment: *"Вроде бы условие в моем цикле истинно"* --- это лишь только твои домыслы. Бери отладку в руки (ссылка выше в самом вопросе) и дебажь код....  и в целом код кривой совершенно. Ты не совсем понимаешь, что ты пишешь